# get temp file path using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
    <div>
    <label class="control-label" for="Name">Add XML</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" accept=".xml"/>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#upload').change(function(){
            alert();//get temp filepath
        });
    });
</script>
```

And I want to get the temp file path of the uploaded file whenever it is selected **using JS/JQuery**.

How can I do it?

Comment: There is no "temporary file path".

Answer (score 1):

It isn't uploaded until the form is submitted. There is no temporary path to get when it is selected, only the original, local path (which is not accessible to in-browser JS for privacy/security reasons).